# Android - Developer Console - Possible problems in changing package of my apk

Tags: android, package

I have uploaded an app with this package name: com.madx.pratonews
so I see my app in the Play Store with this link https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.madx.pratonews

If in the next version i uploaded a new apk with a different package name (e.g. com.madx.news)
will the PlayStore link change to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.madx.news?
If it will, the older link will disappear?

I would like to know because I have an updating system that read the last version of the app directly from the GooglePlay website, so that if I change package name there will be problems with the updating of the older apps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you want to update it, you have to use the same package name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the same package name for an app update!
The package name of an app cannot be changed.

From Dianne Hackborn:

> Things That Cannot Change:
>
> The most obvious and visible of these is the “manifest package name,”
>   the unique name you give to your application in its
>   AndroidManifest.xml. The name uses a Java-language-style naming
>   convention, with Internet domain ownership helping to avoid name
>   collisions. For example, since Google owns the domain “google.com”,
>   the manifest package names of all of our applications should start
>   with “com.google.” It’s important for developers to follow this
>   convention in order to avoid conflicts with other developers.
>
> Once you publish your application under its manifest package name,
>   this is the unique identity of the application forever more. Switching
>   to a different name results in an entirely new application, one that
>   can’t be installed as an update to the existing application.

Other things you cannot change: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html